# Converting and formating JSON objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, react-native

I Have this JSON object:

```
{
"date": "01/01/2020",
"name": "New Year",
"type": "International Holiday",
"description": "",
"type_code": "1"
}
```

I need to create another JSON object with this pattern:

```
{
   "01/01/2020":{
      "selected":true,
      "marked":true,
      "selectedColor":"green"
   }
}
```

For now, I just need the value in `date` field to be the key's name of the new object.
Any sugestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

```
const object = {

      "date": "01/01/2020",
      "name": "New Year",
      "type": "International Holiday",
      "description": "",
      "type_code": "1"
};


const newObject = {};

newObject[object.date] = {
      "selected":true,
      "marked":true,
      "selectedColor":"green"
};

console.log(newObject); // result
```